# Make overlay box stay inside of a picture

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make some hover effects over an image. See a [demosite here](http://vouzalis.dk/hover-effect.html). I am getting stuck now, because I would like the box there is coming when you hover to be centered on each image, no matter what the image size is.

I have tried to place the hover with padding, but that is not a good solution. Does anybody knows how I can center the gradient overlay on each picture, no matter the size og the picture?

```css
.hovereffect {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
}

.hovereffect .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.hovereffect:hover .overlay {
  background-color: rgba(170,170,170,0.4);
}

.hovereffect h2, .hovereffect img {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.hovereffect img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.hovereffect:hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.hovereffect h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.hovereffect a.info {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 7px 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
  transform: scale(1.5);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 85%;
  width: 85%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20%;
  left: 8%;
  padding: 70px;
}

.hovereffect:hover a.info {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

```html
    <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="hovereffect">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.capitalhyundai.ca/wp-content/uploads/sites/385/2017/08/2017-hyundai-elantra-gt-interior-view.jpg" alt="text"></img>
          <div class="overlay">
             
             <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/><br/>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <div class="hovereffect">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.carzone.ie/newcar/assets/img/models/kiasportage-abb0540cd673ba0e6dd80d5e1edc9c64.jpg" alt="text"></img>
          <div class="overlay">
             
             <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/><br/>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="hovereffect">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://solcontrolcustomsandtint.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/car-audio-system-sound-4.jpg" alt="text"></img>
          <div class="overlay">
             
             <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: since the images are not filling their parent container, you would need to know the size of the image. the problem you're facing ist, that the container has an explicit size by ading the bootstrap classes for columns...

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I just updated my code so it is more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firt make the image container `inline-block` so that its width is defined by its content then you can easily adjust the overlay:

```css
.hovereffect {
  display:inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
}

.hovereffect .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.hovereffect:hover .overlay {
  background-color: rgba(170,170,170,0.4);
}

.hovereffect h2, .hovereffect img {
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.hovereffect img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.hovereffect:hover img {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.hovereffect h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.hovereffect a.info {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 85%;
  width: 85%;
  top:7.5%; /* (100% - 85%)/2 */
  left:7.5%;
  position: absolute;
}

.hovereffect:hover a.info {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="hovereffect">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.capitalhyundai.ca/wp-content/uploads/sites/385/2017/08/2017-hyundai-elantra-gt-interior-view.jpg" alt="text"></img>
          <div class="overlay">
             
             <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/><br/>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <div class="hovereffect">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.carzone.ie/newcar/assets/img/models/kiasportage-abb0540cd673ba0e6dd80d5e1edc9c64.jpg" alt="text"></img>
          <div class="overlay">
             
             <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/><br/>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="hovereffect">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://solcontrolcustomsandtint.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/car-audio-system-sound-4.jpg" alt="text"></img>
          <div class="overlay">
             
             <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is pretty pretty cool, thanks. How can I control how big the hover box is? I would like that it got a little bit bigger on the right and left side

Comment: @Mv27 simply adjust the width of `a.info` and make sure to also adjust the left property to keep it centre ;)

Comment: That is just perfect. Thank you a lot